# SVN-ANT Error - "is not a working copy"

Tags: svn, ant, svnkit, svnant

I read related question before submitting this question but wasn't able to find the exact question that has the same issue as mine.

I am trying to setup some automation on a windows box. I have ant target to do update and I have used eclipse as my java development editor. Windows box have **svn client (TortoiseSVN)**  installed and I **used that to get a fresh checkout** from my repository once the project was checked out, I executed the ant target. The result was following.

```
    C:\svncheckout\Automation>ant update-svn
    Buildfile: build.xml

    update-svn:
          [svn]  started ...
          [svn] svn: 'C:\svncheckout\Automation' is not a working copy
          [svn] svn: Cannot read from 'C:\svncheckout\Automation\.svn\format': C:\svncheck
    out\Automation\.svn\format (The system cannot find the file specified)
          [svn] svn: 'C:\svncheckout\Automation' is not a working copy
          [svn] svn: Cannot read from 'C:\svncheckout\Automation\.svn\format': C:\svncheck
    out\Automation\.svn\format (The system cannot find the file specified)
          [svn]  failed !

    BUILD FAILED
    C:\svncheckout\Automation\build.xml:198: Cannot update dir C:\svncheckout\Automation
```

Here is my ant target, and after reading some forums I found out that its better to explicitly tell the target to run with `svnkit` I have removed actual username and password.

```
<!-- target to update working copy -->
<target name="update-svn">
     <svn svnkit="true" javahl="false" username="guest" password="guest">
         <update dir= "${checkout}/Automation" revision="HEAD"/>
     </svn>
</target>
```

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a compatiblity problem between the svn and svnant. 
For example

svn --version
svn, version 1.6.15 (r1038135)
compiled Nov 24 2010, 15:10:19

TortoiseSVN 1.6.12, Build 20536 - 32 Bit , 2010/11/24 20:59:01
Subversion 1.6.15, 
apr 1.3.8
apr-utils 1.3.9
neon 0.29.5
OpenSSL 0.9.8p 16 Nov 2010
zlib 1.2.3

apache-ant
1.7.0\bin\ant -version
Apache Ant version 1.7.0 compiled on December 13 2006

Combined with svnant-1.2.1.zip it will generate the error with "working copy" and missing .svn/format file
If svnant-1.3.1.zip the issue there's no issue.

Comment: upvote. I strongly suspect this is the (my) problem. SVN 1.7  went from a `.svn` folder at each sub-folder  to a single `.svn` at the checkout root.  My NAnt script runs fine on our (Jenkins) build server where "sub root folders" are separate checkouts. On my local machine I have a single checkout at our "root" and the script fails.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all, really. Your `C:\svncheckout\Automation` is not a working copy. To verify that, you can check whether the `C:\svncheckout\Automation\.svn\format` exists (and it probably doesn't.)

Which folder did you checkout to?

Could it be that you performed an `export` operation instead of `checkout`? Or that the `.svn` folder got deleted somehow?

Could it be that you checked out to a different folder (not `C:\svncheckout\Automation`)?

Could it be that the `Automation` folder doesn't exist in the repository? (You can check with TortoiseSVN's Repo-Browser.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it could be solved by simply switching to javahl.

```
<svn svnkit="false" javahl="true">
    <update dir="${source.dir}" revision="HEAD" />
</svn>
```

**Edit:** I think the general problem is rooted in the workspace being created with a newer version of subversion compared to the library used in ant, in your case SVNKit. I guess that on my system javahl is present in a recent enough version, whereas SVNKit isn't - so that switching to javahl solved my problem. You can probably solve your problem by updating the SVNKit libraries used by your ant skript. This [post at tigris](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2218417) also points in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer says to switch to javahl but it created be ton of problem so in my experience the best solution is to turn off javahl.

```
enter code here

<!-- target to update working copy -->
<target name="update-svn">
     <svn svnkit="true" javahl="false" username="username" password="password">
        <cleanup dir="${checkout}/myframework"/>
        <update dir= "${checkout}/myframework" revision="HEAD"/>
     </svn>
</target>
```

I have added the cleanup just svn cleanup because my ant script is running to take care automation process in hudson. So to avoid any cleanup process I decided to add that.